# Where would uploads go on AWS S3 if you don't specify folder

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I'm using the iOS AWS SDK to upload files to S3 and everything works perfectly fine. I normally upload files to a group/filename.jpg which has caused no problems.

However, for some reason (separate issue) the group is empty, causing the upload url path to be /filename.jpg. The image appears to upload successfully as the transfer utility reports upload progress, however, I don't see it anywhere in my bucket.

Is it likely that this image has uploaded to somewhere, or not uploaded given it doesn't have a folder. If I remote the first '/' so it is just filename.jpg then it goes to the root directory, but not if the '/' is included.

Thanks

Comment: It will be in the bucket you are connected into

Comment: It's not in the root directory, which is where I would have expected it to be.

Comment: Don't prefix object keys with `/`.  The console would probably try to consider `/foo` to be an object in a "folder" named [empty string].  Use `aws s3api list-objects` and you will likely find it.

Comment: Thanks. I've kinda guessed it shouldn't be prefixed with / and changed my setup to accommodate this. However, it's more of a concern as to where these items have uploaded to. Using list-objects they don't appear to show.

Answer (score 2):

First, are you setting correctly your bucketName in the `uploadRequest` method ?
`uploadRequest.bucket = "myBucket"`

Secondly : There is no "Folders" on S3, only Keys.

> The console uses the key name prefixes (Development/, Finance/, and
>   Private/) and delimiter ('/') to present a folder structur

Maybe can you use the `/` only on your `xxx/` and not `/filename.jpg` ?

Cheers

Comment: Thanks. Yeah sorry I mean keys, it's just when I'm looking for 'folders' I forget they are keys!

Everything appears to be fine as when I add a prefix to the first '/' then uploads work. It seems that with the '/' as a prefix it uploads but to nowhere. But I can't believe it doesn't upload somewhere, it's just finding out where. A bug perhaps, or you just must not use a '/' prefix..

Comment: Exactly ;) 
Let us know if you find a solution